# https not pointing to the same subdomain

Tags: domain-name-system, https

I am setting up my DNS records. If I do the following it gives me the correct IP.

```
nslookup subdomainA.domain.com
```

But this:

```
nslookup https://subdomainA.domain.com
```

gives me

```
server can't find https://subdomainA.domain.com: NXDOMAIN
```

unless I add a record

```
A    *.domain.com    aaa.aaa.aaa.aaa
```

then everything works.

But I dont want to do this because I want to point a subdomainB to another IP and not have its HTTPS go back to aaa.aaa.aaa.aaa. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

https://subdomainA.domain.com is not a domain, it's a protocol "https://" with a domain "subdomainA.domain.com".

This request

```
nslookup https://subdomainA.domain.com
```

Should result in an error. I'm surprised that adding the wildcard record works. I don't use wildcard records because I've never needed one, and unless you understand exactly what you're doing you probably don't either.

Comment: yes, I also don't know how it works. Maybe its some other problem. I will continue looking. Thanks for clarifying.